# Is there a way to use less memory in the web browser when loading models?

Tags: autodesk-forge

NWD File Size : 32.5Mb

SVF Translate Size : 302Mb

Web Browser consumes around 2.8Gb memory when loading single model (not Memory Allocation for Large Models) in FORGE Viewer and consumes around 7Gb memory for multiple models which is bigger than 4Gb in typical laptops.

Is there a way to use less memory in the web browser when loading the model?

I also would like to know if there is any memory improvements in SVF(not in SVF2).

Answer (score 0):

SVF2 is made for bigger files. So please use SVF2.